# Product Option Price Substract

Tags: opencart2.x

For example: My product price is 20$ and it has many option

- Black : +5$
- Blue : -5$

But inside dropdownlist in product detail it show

- black (25$)
- blue (25$)

what I want to do is:

- black (25$)
- blue (15$)

Inside Product controller I found this line like this

```
$price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false));
```

What should i to do?

Comment: In that case set product price to $0, now for Black(+25), Blue (+15)